# warnings when running octave from python

Tags: python, warnings, octave, oct2py

I am using oct2py python library to run octave script but I get the following error that I don't understand:

```
warning: function C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\share\octave\packages\statistics-1.5.0\shadow\mean.m shadows a core library function
warning: called from
    C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\share\octave\packages\statistics-1.5.0\PKG_ADD at line 11 column 3
    load_packages_and_dependencies at line 56 column 5
    load_packages at line 53 column 3**
```

How can I solve this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste text as text, not as screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error but a warning, which should not prevent the execution. It warns you that a function defined in the `statistics` package of Octave (in the file `C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\share\octave\packages\statistics-1.5.0\shadow\mean.m`) has the same name than the `mean()` function that is built-in in Octave (i.e. available without any additional package).

I do not have this file in my Octave 5.2 installation, but it looks intentional in your installation, as the new definition is inside a `shadow` subfolder, meaning that the developers explicitely want to overload the `mean()` function. I guess (but can't be sure without seeing the file) that they wanted to add some argument(s)/option(s) to the original function.

Comment: Should I delete it? The 'mean.m' octave file I mean

Comment: @Wallflower Why would you do that? The file is here for a reason, and removing it may break some code in the statistics package. Sometimes a warning is just informative, without the need to bring modifications.

Comment: I tried to turn it off using warning('off','all') but I still get it :/